# How do I reference the right html document?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

**Initial situation**

My function is:

```
function MyFunction01() {
  const button = document.getElementById("button");
  button.className = "button is-primary is-loading"
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(e => {
    console.log(e); // Here, you can see the returned value.
    button.className = "button is-dark";
  }).MyFunction02();
}
```

**Problem**

An error is returned when executing

> ReferenceError: document is not defined

Probably because the ID of the button is in a different file, namely sidebar.html.

**Question**

How can I refer the Button ID to the correct document so that the error does not occur?

Comment: I'm assuming `MyFunction01` us within the client HTML enclosed in `<script></script>` tags?

Comment: @TheWizEd
So far yes, but I would like to move the function to a separate script, so that the html actually contains only html.

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: If you are using templated html then they documentation will be in a separate html file with then gets included into a template using scriplets.  Otherwise you can hardwire it into the script tags of an html file.  So the answer I guess is you'll know which html file your referencing by put the code into that file either by doing it yourself or using scriptlets to do it for you

Comment: I posted as an answer but someone deleted my post.  Not sure why.  But here is how to put html, css and javascript into seperate files [HTML Service Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices)